# IP Camera working on port 1024 but not on port 1025 for ONVIF

Tags: c#, port, ip-camera, onvif

I have a problem with my IP Camera. I can enter the camera feed successfully on port 1024 which I have configured in the IP Camera and the router on this address in Chrome:
**http://192.168.1.4:1024/web/admin.html**

Now there is an ONVIF setting for the IP Camera which I have set like this on port 1025:
    [image]

I have also on the router done port forwarding for both port 1024 and 1025 like this:
    [image]

Now when I enter the below URL in the Chrome Browser, I get the below error:
    **http://192.168.1.4:1025/web/admin.html**
    `<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>HTTP GET method not implemented</faultstring>`

I wonder what this means and why no stream is coming for the above URL on port 1025?
[image]

```
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

Comment: Have you tried to use other ports? Like 1030, 1040?

Comment: I tried port 1030 with the same problem now. I reconfigured the port on the IP camera and router.

Comment: I use a software called Onvif Device Manager also. And this software finds my camera feed on: `http://192.168.1.4:1030/onvif/device_service` and then shows another URL when the stream is coming:  `rtsp://192.168.1.4:554/11` but the first URL here in Chrome shows the SAME error as in my original post in the red rectangle and the second URL (rtsp) doesnt work at all and google search results is coming instead?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here:

1. Accessing the ONVIF interface through a browser
2. Streaming and NAT traversal

For the first problem, ONVIF works with soap, and therefore it expects to have POST requests. Your browser thinks that it is connecting to a web page and sends a HTTP GET request that makes no sense for soap-based protocols, such as ONVIF.

The second problem is that your router is doing NAT, and moving RTSP streams through NAT is painful. You will find a lot of literature for VOIP, that uses RTSP and here the problem is exactly the same. You have two possible solutions:

1. Using HTTP as transport for your video instead of any other transport. This is the only NAT-friendly transport in ONVIF
2. Using a router that supports full cone NAT, configuring several rules in the router ahve making sure that the camera uses always the same ports for streaming.